# ADXL345 Arduino UNO data_ready interrupt

Tags: arduino, interrupts, accelerometer

I would like the sensor values to be updated each 10ms(100Hz) and then run the algorithm and repeat the same process. However, after timing the algorithm it is taking only 2ms, I think the data_ready interrupt is not working as expected. Physical hardware connection is from INT1 of ADXL345 to pin2 of the UNO.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/power.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL 

volatile int sensor_update=0;
```

---

```
//Write to ADXL345 registers
void writeTo(int device, byte address, byte val) {
   Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
   Wire.write(address);        // send register address
   Wire.write(val);        // send value to write
   Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}
```

---

```
//ISR function

  void interrupt(void){
  sensor_update=1;
  }
```

---

```
void buzz(int targetPin, long frequency, long length) {
  long delayValue = 1000000/frequency/2; // calculate the delay value between transitions
  //// 1 second's worth of microseconds, divided by the frequency, then split in half since
  //// there are two phases to each cycle
  long numCycles = frequency * length/ 1000; // calculate the number of cycles for proper timing
  //// multiply frequency, which is really cycles per second, by the number of seconds to 
  //// get the total number of cycles to produce
  for (long i=0; i < numCycles; i++){ // for the calculated length of time...
    digitalWrite(targetPin,HIGH); // write the buzzer pin high to push out the diaphram
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait for the calculated delay value
    digitalWrite(targetPin,LOW); // write the buzzer pin low to pull back the diaphram
    delayMicroseconds(delayValue); // wait againf or the calculated delay value
  }
}

/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);

void setup(void) 
{
  if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.println("Accelerometer Test"); Serial.println("");

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);// buzzer output pin

  /* Initialise the sensor */
  if(!accel.begin())
  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the ADXL345 ... check your connections */
    //Serial.println("Ooops, no ADXL345 detected ... Check your wiring!");
    while(1);
  }

  /* Set the range to whatever is appropriate for your project */
  accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_16_G);
  accel.setDataRate(ADXL345_DATARATE_100_HZ);
  // displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
  // displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_4_G);
  // displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_2_G);

  //Create an interrupt that will trigger when a tap is detected.
  attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);

  writeTo(0x1D, 0x2E, 0);
  writeTo(0x1D, 0x2F, 0);
  writeTo(0x1D, 0x2E, 128);
  writeTo(0x1D, 0x2F, 127);
}

void loop(void) 
{


  if(sensor_update==1 ){
    //When sensor_update is set to 1 in the ISR,the algorithm process the data from the accelerometer being updated every 10ms(100Hz)
     sensor_update=0;//reset

  }
}
```

Update:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_ADXL345_U.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/power.h>


#define F_CPU 16000000UL 



int state=0; //0--active detecting; 1--sleeping
int state_count=0; //sleeping trigger between 2 states
double mag[40];
int i=0;
double acc_rate[39];
int hunt_sub=0;
int exit_marker=-10,trough_marker=-30,peak_marker=-10;
volatile int sensor_update=0;
byte buff[1] ;


volatile unsigned long time=0, time0=0,time_dis=0,time_array[40]={0};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Read ADXL345 registers
void readFrom(int device, byte address, int num, byte buff[]) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        //sends address to read from
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission

Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device (initiate again)
Wire.requestFrom(device, num);    // request 1 byte from device

int i = 0;
while(Wire.available())    //device may send less than requested (abnormal)
{ 
buff[i] = Wire.read(); // receive a byte
i++;
}
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}

//Write to ADXL345 registers
void writeTo(int device, byte address, byte val) {
Wire.beginTransmission(device); //start transmission to device 
Wire.write(address);        // send register address
Wire.write(val);        // send value to write
Wire.endTransmission(); //end transmission
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//ISR function

void interrupt(void){
sensor_update=1;
//  time0 = time;
//   time= millis();
//        time_dis=time-time0;
//        if(i<40){
//          time_array[i]=time_dis;
//    }
 //readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff); //clear interrupt
}





/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified accel = Adafruit_ADXL345_Unified(12345);





void setup(void) 
{
if (F_CPU == 16000000) clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);
Serial.begin(9600);
//Serial.println("Accelerometer Test"); Serial.println("");

pinMode(4, OUTPUT);// buzzer output pin
//pinMode(2, INPUT);

/* Initialise the sensor */
if(!accel.begin())
{
/* There was a problem detecting the ADXL345 ... check your connections */
//Serial.println("Ooops, no ADXL345 detected ... Check your wiring!");
while(1);
}

/* Set the range to whatever is appropriate for your project */
accel.setRange(ADXL345_RANGE_16_G);
accel.setDataRate(ADXL345_DATARATE_1_56_HZ);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_8_G);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_4_G);
// displaySetRange(ADXL345_RANGE_2_G);

/* Display some basic information on this sensor */
//displaySensorDetails();

/* Display additional settings (outside the scope of sensor_t) */
//displayDataRate();
//displayRange();
//Serial.println("");

//Create an interrupt that will trigger when a tap is detected.

writeTo(0x1D, 0x2E, 0);// disable interrupt

attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);
writeTo(0x53, 0x2F, 0); //map data_ready to INT1
writeTo(0x53, 0x2E, 128); //enable data_ready




}

void loop(void) 
{


sensors_event_t event; 
readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff); //read the acceleration data from the ADXL345   (device,register to read from,number of bytes,array to store in)  
while(buff[0] & 0b10000000){
accel.getEvent(&event);
} 

 Serial.print("buff: "); Serial.print(buff[0], BIN); Serial.print("  ");
 delay(10);

 mag_calculation (event.acceleration.x, event.acceleration.y, event.acceleration.z);
 detachInterrupt(0);


 if(sensor_update==1 ){
 //When sensor_update is set to 1 in the ISR,the algorithm process the data from the accelerometer being updated every 10ms(100Hz)
 //rest of algorithm is here
 sensor_update=0;//reset
 attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);


 }


 }
```

Comment: Might be more at home in the Arduino stackexchange

Comment: I don't see where buzz() function is called in your code. Also, why are you using delay in microseconds? Doesn't arduino library provide _delay_ms() or something similar?

Comment: I posted the code related to the interrupt problem I am having, others things are irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line from the loop:

```
/* Get a new sensor event */ 
  interrupt();
```

You don't need to call the interrupt routine. Interrupts work by *interrupting* the main program flow when ever an interrupt condition is met, then executing the *interrupt service routine* (in your case `interrupt()`) then back to where ever the program left off.

`attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);` is a function that enables an interrupt, in this case rising edge on INT0, and tells it what function to jump to (`interrupt`) when the interrupt condition is met.

The way you have it now, it is setting `sensor_update=1;` as fast as the loop can loop.

**From comments:**

```
void loop(void) 
{
    sensors_event_t event;
```

The following will loop forever if the the flag is set as buff[0] is not updated:

```
    readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);
    while(buff[0] & 0b10000000){
        accel.getEvent(&event);
    }
```

Instead read the data then check the flag using a `do` loop:

```
    do {
        accel.getEvent(&event);
        readFrom(0x53, 0x30, 1, buff);
    } while(buff[0] & 0b10000000);
```

The rest of the code:

```
    Serial.print("buff: "); Serial.print(buff[0], BIN); Serial.print("  ");

    delay(10);
    mag_calculation (event.acceleration.x, 
                     event.acceleration.y, 
                     event.acceleration.z);
```

Remove the detach interrupt, it is not needed. The MCU will clear its interrupt flag when the code enters the ISR. By detaching here, the interrupt is disabled, and if `sensor_update` was 0 then it would never be enabled again by your following code.

```
    detachInterrupt(0);

    if(sensor_update==1 ) {
        sensor_update=0;//reset
```

Likewise remove the attach interrupt.

```
        attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to read some register, e.g. data, to clear the interrupt flag on the ADXL and thus generate further interrupts.

Comment: I am using a library to obtain the data from the ADXL that's why I am not explicitly reading any register in my code. Is there any other way of clearing the flag?

Comment: Looking at the ADXL data sheet you have to read a register to clear the interrupt pin on the device. Otherwise the pin will just stay outputting active low. There is no other way. If I understand correctly, for the DATA_READY interrupt, which you are using, this is the data registers, so using the library function that reads the data out should clear the ADXL interrupt pin.

Comment: Yeah since I am reading the samples using the library the interrupt pin should be cleared. Not sure what's causing this.writeTo(0x1D, 0x2E, 128); //enabling DATA_READY interrupt
writeTo(0x1D, 0x2F, 127);      //MAP DATA_READY to INT1 INT_SOURCE register is not used

Comment: You have to explicitly read the data after `if(sensor_update==1 ){`, is that what you are doing? If so, please update your code.

Comment: the library from adafruit is taking care of this, I just removed the code in the loop to focus on the interrupt problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the library is taking care of it. Are you doing an ADXL read? If you don't have the function in there it won't be called. Is that the complete loop code in your question?

Comment: yes I am doing a read from the loop I am not showing it in the code.x= event.acceleration.x , y event.acceleration.y, z = event.acceleration.z

Comment: Please post the complete loop otherwise it will just be guessing. :)

Comment: inside the loop I have                       if(sensor_update==1){                           sensors_event_t event;                         accel.getEvent(&event);                                            mag_calculation(event.acceleration.x,event.acceleration.y,event.acceleration.z);  //call the the magnitude calculation function                                                               // rest of algorithm                                          sensors_update=0;                                            }

Comment: Some troubleshooting suggestions: 1. Put it on 1s update rate and check that the INT1 pin is being toggled. 2. Read the ADXL interrupt flag register before and after reading the data and set it was set then cleared.

Comment: 1.checking if INT1 is toggling with an LED for example? 2. read the INT_SOURCE register before and after reading the data right?

Comment: 1. yep, or with a multimeter (thats why reduce output rate to 1Hz so you can see it)  high voltage is interrupt pin active for the ADXL. 2. yep, just check flag is cleared.... Do you have to set pin 2 as INPUT for the interrupt to work I wonder?

Comment: I have reduced the output rate to 1.56Hz and connected the output of ADXL345 from INT1 to the LED. other side of LED is connected to ground. LED is always off, it seems the interrupt is not toggling. Same result with multimeter. I have put pin2 as an input and it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I have changed the device to 0x53 instead of 0x1D and now the LED is always on, still not toggling tough.

Comment: reading the INT_source register doesn't seem to toggle the interrupt either.

Comment: Are any of the flags set in the int_source register when you read it? Sorry, I mean when you read the register what is its value?

Comment: the byte I read is 131 = 10000011

Comment: Hmmm, so the data ready flag is set, which is good. Try reading the data until the date ready flag clears. e.g. `while(readFrom(ADXL_ADDRESS,0x30) & 0b10000000) { accel.getEvent(&event); } `Note: you can print out in binary like so: `Serial.println(value, BIN);` to save having to convert decimal to binary for troubleshooting

Comment: Reading the data until the flag clears and detaching the interrupt after the reading seem to toggle the interrupt properly as I see the LED toggling but for some reason nothing is printed on the serial. I have attached the latest code above. Does that imply keeping this structure would work with the algorithm?

Comment: I have made some comments in the answer. The LED toggling is good.

Comment: Ahh that is great, good luck with the project :D

Comment: I am trying to use the activity and inactivity interrupt features to save power at the moment, I created a new post for clarity maybe you could help help; ADXL345 Arduino UNO Activity Inactivity interrupt